# Handling connection errors when connecting to Azure using Connect-AzAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I've written a runbook Powershell script. However I am having issues catching any errors I receive using the Connect-AzAccount command.  It seems that wrapping the Connect-AzAccount in a try catch does not work.  The script continues.  How can I handle the errors returned using this command?

```
try
{
    The catch is never executed even when there is an error
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity;
}
catch
{
    write-output "Error connecting to Azure";
    write-output  $_.Exception.message;
    $response = .\SendEmail.ps1 -To "xxx@xxx.com" -From "xxx@xxx" -Subject "xxxx" -Message "xxxxx";
}
```

The error message below is rendered to the console automatically

```
Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
Connect-AzAccount : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned 
to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Content:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}

Headers:
Content-Length: xx
Content-Type: xxxxx
Date: xxxxx
Server: xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx

At line:71 char:5
+     Connect-AzAccount -Identity;
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], CredentialUnavailableException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in order for the `catch` to be executed, you should include `-ErrorAction Stop`.

So your code should read:
`Connect-AzAccount -Identity -ErrorAction Stop`

You could also set:
`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at the top of your cmdlet.